# Firebase Analytics Unable to log as E-Commerce IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-analytics

I have issue with latest library of Firebase v(4.6.0) + Swift 3

Right now, my ecommerce event tracked as normal event. i dont know what caused this issue. is it library or my code.

Track ECommerce add_to_wishlist

```
AnalyticsManager.sharedInstance.firebaseTrackEvent(
    eventName: AnalyticsEventAddToWishlist,
    eventParameter: [
      "Route": "\(originCode)-\(destinationCode)" as NSObject,
      "no_of_passenger": "\(self.adultCount)\(self.childCount)\(self.infantCount)" as NSObject,
      "CampaignType": "\(defaults.string(forKey: "campaignType")!)" as NSObject
    ]
)
```

Global function

```
func firebaseTrackEvent(eventName: String, eventParameter: [String: NSObject]) {
    Analytics.logEvent(eventName, parameters: eventParameter)
}
```

[Unsuccess Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug3CH.png)

This is happen to add_to_wishlist(AnalyticsEventAddToWishlist), view_search_results(AnalyticsEventViewSearchResults), add_payment_info(AnalyticsEventAddPaymentInfo) but for ecommerce_purchase, im unable to track it as e-commerce tracking.

[Success Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I49wh.png)

Answer (score 0):

"add_payment_info", "add_to_wish_list" and "view_search_results" are different events from e-commerce event (the names are different). If you meant as conversion event, you should mark them as conversion on Firebase Analytics dashboard.

Comment: @Ayus Salleh I too have same problem, can you please share your suggestion if you managed to show ecommerce_purchase as conversion event ?

Comment: Hi @adbitx,
ecommerce_purchase are by default marked as conversion and that is not editable, so it should show up as conversion event by default in the firebase console, however it is not showing up in my case too as with the Ayus Salleh mentioned in his question. If you have any suggestion please share, thanks.

Comment: I think this might be the issue with the Debug View web page. Can you please take a look at the debug log in the XCode console log when the event is logged, and see if the event has any parameter that indicates that it is a conversion event? If so, the event should be marked correctly, but the web page just doesn't show it right.